# Pluralsight Advanced - Movie Content not displayed in Content table

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I am walking through Pluralsight Advanced Orchard course.
I just created the Movie module and created a sample movie.
It was working fine but I did notice that the sample movie did not show up in Manage Content page.

[image]

I can only get to the list by going to Content Definition and select "List Items"

[image]

Then I can see the list of Movie item

[image]

This is what I got so far. I followed the steps and don't see what I have missed. I did notice that Orchard has changed slightly from 1.4 to 1.10 appearance wise. I wonder if this also has something to do with the version difference.

Any tips would be appreciated! Thank you

```
namespace Pluralsight.Movies {
public class Migrations : DataMigrationImpl {

    public int Create() {

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Movie", builder=> 
            builder.WithPart("CommonPart")
                .WithPart("TitlePart")
                .WithPart("AutoroutePart")
                .WithPart("BodyPart")
                .Creatable()
                .Draftable());
        return 1;
    }

    public int UpdateFrom1()
    {
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Movie", builder =>
            builder.WithPart("BodyPart", partBuilder=>partBuilder.WithSetting("BodyTypePartSettings.Flavor", "text")));
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `.Listable()` into your type definition. Note that if you already ran those migrations, unless you reset the database, it won't execute again, so you'll have to put it into a `UpdateFrom2()` method.

Note that this setting can also be checked from the content definition screen after the fact.

> Note: I think the PluralSight course was written at a time when this setting didn't exist, and everything was listable.

Comment: Yes, that is what I missed. Thank you for your answer!!